# How come there's still so much gas in TWD?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In The Walking Dead: A New Frontier Episode 1, Javier finds a car with a lot of fuel in it and pumps it out. The problem is that this episode takes place 5 years since the zombies hit and according to Bing gas breaks down within 6 months.

Is there any logical explanation as to how the survivors can still find usable gasoline this far into the apocalypse?

Comment: The short lifespan of gas is overstated. My backup car runs fine on gas I pumped into it a lot more than six months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a number of explanations for this:

1. They've got to the point where all petrol (Gasoline) has gone bad and they've moved onto diesel. Diesel, although it does go bad can be 'resurrected' by filtering using an easily made filter. [Can diesel go bad?](https://www.primalsurvivor.net/store-diesel/#:%7E:text=Filtering%20Old%20Diesel%20Fuel&text=Filtering%20can%20clean%20the%20old,drain%20off%20the%20dirty%20diesel.)
2. They're still using petrol but they've found petrol that has either been stored especially well and/or has been treated with an additive to increase it's lifespan [Treating petrol](https://fuelandfriction.com/trucking-pro/prolong-fuels-life-fuel-stabilizer/#:%7E:text=A%20fuel%20stabilizer%20is%20a,of%20storage%20due%20to%20oxidation.)
3. They've discovered either a way of refining 'new' fuel or found someone who is doing this. This has happened in '[Fear the walking dead](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3743822/)' which is, after all happening at around the same time [Fear the walking dead oil fields](https://www.syfy.com/syfy-wire/the-oil-fields-of-fear-the-walking-dead)
4. We're right at the end of 'usable' fuel supplies (See other theories above) after which point, if the series were to continue, new alternatives of either fuel or transportation methods would begin to emerge.
5. People have discovered alternatives for traditional fuel such as alcohol (ethanol). Vehicles *will* run on alcohol but the more impure it is, the more it will wreck the vehicle. Plus, it depends on your priorities when it comes to transport and drinking !
6. It's simply a plot device that stretches the believable. Although it's scientific fact that fuel is going to run out and spoil, the writers might not want to burdened with that fact !

Comment: Definitely number five, but a great answer addressing the in-universe possibilities.

Comment: I gotta point out the fact that that Fear The Walking Dead takes place in a different universe from the games and the comics... even though that's probably not really relevant.

Comment: Hi0401 - Good point, however the generalities of the question (and the answer) could be applied to pretty much any post-apocalyptic fiction. Indeed, the are sections within the books of Sarah Lyons Fleming that directly address the fuel issue... https://www.sarahlyonsfleming.com/

Comment: If the tank the gas is in is full, so that there is as little air as possible, then the longer the fuel keeps. However, it the fuel contains ethanol, there is literally no way for it to stay good for more than six months, even if it is stored in cold place and in sealed container with as little air as possible. 
That being said, if the car has simple engine  (say early 60's at most), you can try and use it. Also - last but not least - for example, in WW2 September Campaign, when Polish tanks ran out of diesel fuel, they used filtered vegetable oil mixed with raw ethanol with great effect.